# Can I combine these url-patterns in a servlet-mapping?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, url-pattern

I have a requirement to support /{servlet}/history, and have many servlets that need to support this.  I'm using Tomcat, FWIW.

The following works, but I'm wondering if there's a way to combine all patterns into one line and avoid adding a url-pattern for every servlet that needs to support the history pattern.  I've tried several options and failed.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>History</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.HistoryServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>History</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/aDifferentServlet/history/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/someOtherOne/history/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/anotherExample/history/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>aDifferentServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.foo.aDifferentServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>aDifferentServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/aDifferentServlet/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "for every servlet"? You're mapping a single servlet to multiple paths.

Comment: Sorry, I'm referring to servlet* in the url-patterns.  Each of those paths really represents a servlet.  For servletA, I need to support getting the history of everything that has passed through servletA, B, C, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to have only one URL pattern, you'd need to specify a common prefix (folder) pattern like `/history/*` or a suffix (extension) pattern like `*.history`. You cannot have an URL pattern with wildcard matches on both sides like `*/history/*`. Your best bet is to have the history servlet mapped on `/history/*` and change the URLs accordingly to for example `/history/aDifferentServlet` (this part is then available by `request.getPathInfo()` in the history servlet).

If changing the URLs is undesireable, you'd need to create a `Filter` or rewrite the servlets that they forward to the history servlet whenever the request URI matches the `*/history/*` pattern.

Comment: */history/ -- I tried this one and server and it is not working

Answer (score 0):

pattern can either end in an asterisk or start with one (to denote a file extension mapping).

more info at:

http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/#&slider1=1

```
The url-pattern specification:

        *A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ 
        suffix is used for path mapping.
        *A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
        *A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" 
        servlet of the application. In this case the 
        servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path 
        info is null.
        *All other strings are used for exact matches only.
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer.  The actual servlet names aren't servlet*, that was just to mask the real names.  Think more like /doStuff, /aDifferentServlet, /login, etc.

Comment: How about like above? Edited the mapping. You always a history thats the common part right?

Comment: Updated to a more informative reply but not a direct answer to your q.